# Python Create fixed banner within console / with console

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, adventure

I am working on a text-based RPG game, and I need a way of displaying the important figures such as remaining life and level so that it is always available to be checked.

Is there a way of creating a stationary banner within the console to display such figures? If not, do I have to create a GUI with the banner and embed the console?

Any alternative solutions that also work would be appreciated, given that it shows the figures at all times.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a TUI layer. You might checkout the `curses` library,[urwid](http://urwid.org/), or even possibly [picotui](https://github.com/pfalcon/picotui).